# Unable to programmatically connect to Tello drone via code

Tags: dji-sdk, tello-drone

I've tried various Tello SDK/wrapper libraries to control a Tello drone programmatically, but with no success. Currently I am focused on using the simpler C# wrapper:

- [TelloSdkCoreNet](https://github.com/8bitbytes/TelloSdkCoreNet)

I am getting a very straight-forward error, but it seems invalid:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

I can confirm that the drone works just fine via the Tello App (for iOS).

Here are some technical details...

I am connecting programmatically to IP Address: 192.168.10.1 with Port: 8889.

Anybody with experience with any of these libraries/scripts have any ideas?

**My problem is now resolved.**

No thanks to the manual, it was not very clear about setting up the network when accessing the drone via the SDK.

Here is the solution below...

> Before running the program from your computer, do the following:
>
> 1. Turn on the Tello drone and wait for it to be initialized.
> 2. Connect your computer (PC/Mac) to the Tello drone WIFI (the SSID should have "Tello" in it).
> 3. Run your program and try sending commands (it should work!).

Comment: You probably wouldn't want to reveal an IP Address...

Comment: Well, this is the IP address for the Drone (specified in the SDK manual).

Comment: Ah, I see, yeah if it's included in the manual than it shouldn't reveal anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is now resolved. I updated my original post to include details for how i resolved it.